# Slogan Homepage - Mal traduzido

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

Este é o texto da homepage do pt.stackoverflow.com :

> Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para professional and enthusiast programmers. É 100% gratuito e não requer registro.

Devia ser corrigido não ?

Comment: Outra: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92/traducao-incompleta-no-tour-do-site. A descrição do site provavelmente é uma única string localizada, utilizada em várias partes do site.

Comment: Pessoal... eu ia reportar isso também mas bastou uma pesquisadinha aqui para ver que já foi reportado CINCO VEZES (pelo menos)... Ver também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingles?cb=1